# Create an entry using the model class

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm struggling creating an entry using sequelize. I have a model Account that has a login, password and type. I declare the account and set login, password and type then I call `Account.create(account)`. The account is created in the database because it has an id generated but the fields are not filled.
When I call create with an object it works fine.

I don't really want to declare an object each time I want to add something in the database, I expect sequelize to use the models I declared.

Here is the code I have

```
//account.model.ts
@Table
export default class Account extends Model<Account> {

    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, field: 'id' })
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, field: 'login' })
    login: string;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, field: 'password' })
    password: string;

    @Column({ type: DataType.ENUM, values: ['USER', 'BOX'], field: 'type' })
    type: string;

    @HasOne(() => Entity)
    entity: Entity;

    toString(): string {
        return "id=" + this.id + " login=" + this.login + " password=" + this.password + " type=" + this.type;
    }

}

//test.ts
let account = new Account();
account.login = "jack";
account.password = "jack";
account.type = "USER";

console.log("account:" + account.toString());
let storedAccount = await Account.create(account);
console.log(storedAccount.toString());
console.log();

console.log("object: { login: 'john', password: 'john', type : 'USER' }");
let storedAccount3 = await Account.create({ login: 'john', password: 'john', type: 'USER' });
console.log(storedAccount3.toString());
```

and this is the output :

```
account:id=null login=jack password=jack type=USER
id=3 login=null password=null type=null

object: { login: 'john', password: 'john', type : 'USER' }
id=4 login=john password=john type=USER
```

I wanted to know if it is the  expected behavior or if I'm doing it wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it by myself, the Model base class has a save() method that does the same as create. So i can call directly account.save()